# How to improve Jenkins server performance?

Tags: performance, jenkins, hudson

Our Jenkins server(linux machine) slows down over a period of time and it gets unresponsive. All the jobs take unexpectedly long time(even though they run on slaves which are different machines from server). One of things I have observed is increase in the number of open files. The number seems to be increasing as shown in the image below. Does anyone have a solution to keep check on this without restarting the server? Also, are there any configurations/tweaks that could improve the performance of the jenkins server?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder if there are some Jenkins jobs for which the compiler and/or the testing is not properly being cleaned up.  I've seen a similar issue on a Windows machine when one of the unit tests left a new copy of Excel running each time it was executed.

Comment: How many jobs and how many builds? If you have a large number of jobs, and each job has a lot of builds I can see this happening. I have my Jenkins setup to delete old jobs or artifacts after so many days or builds. In the job configuration you can look for "Discard old builds"

Comment: @LarryShatzer  We have more than 300 jobs and on average each job would  store 10 builds. Some jobs are heavy and take 3hours time and some are light weight. Overall, the server is used quite extensively majority of the times

Comment: What version are you running? Newer versions have lazy loading which helps performance.

Comment: Till now we were on ~ 1.47 and we just upgraded to 1.502

Comment: Hi Shiva Kumar! We are experiencing the same issues, did you eventually find a solution to this?

Comment: @ThobiasKarlsson: Not much but we increased the file descriptor count on the server, and also started following some guidelines like those mentioned [here](http://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/whitepapers/7WaysToOptimizeJenkins.pdf)

Answer (score 13):

We are using Jenkins for four years and we tried to keep it up-to-date (Jenkins + plug-ins).
Like you we experimented some inconvenience, depending on new versions of Jenkins or plug-ins...
So we decided to stop this "continuous" upgrade

Here are humble tips:

1. Avoid technical debt. Update Jenkins as much as you can, but use only "Long Term Support" versions (latest is 2.138.2)
2. Backup your entire `jenkins_home` before any upgrade!
3. Restart Jenkins every night
4. Add RAM to your server. Jenkins use file system a lot and this will improve caching
5. Define JVM min/max memory parameters with the same value to avoid dynamic reallocation, for example: `-Xms4G -Xmx4G`
6. Add slaves and execute jobs only on slaves

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above, you can also try:

1. Discarding old builds
2. Distribute the builds on multiple slaves, if possible.